# How to put a <script> tag inside a div using jQuery or pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm trying to put a `<script>` tag with some **js** code inside a div, well this is the code that i'm using:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = "var dfpValues = DFP.get().values(); googletag.display(dfpValues.dfpContainer)"
$("#mydiv").html(script);
```

This code puts nothing inside my div, and returns no errors.
Someone know how to do?

Obs: im using ruby(v2) on rails(v4) project, this can change something?

Comment: That works perfectly fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/BvzvV/

Comment: are you including the jquery library?

Comment: why not just add it to the head where all good scripts belong

Comment: What does the markup look like that you're trying to insert this into? Is there a `<div id="mydiv"></div>` (or any element with `id="mydiv"`) in there?

Comment: If the code you are appending results in a document.write that creates content, you won't be able to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I keep the script to be added in a string, then append the string TO the div  (in case there are things in the div, these wont get removed).

```
var scriptString = "<script type='text/javascript'> var dfpValues = DFP.get().values(); googletag.display(dfpValues.dfpContainer) </script>";

$(scriptString).appendTo('#myDiv');
```

Comment: Well appears that i can't append a code that haves script tag, i try this using .text(); and works, i try this using append or appendTo and  nothing happens, obs: i'm in a ruby on rails project

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't be a problem, however I had missed a semicolon at the end of the string. Just added the semicolon.

Don't know what beeing a rubyonrails shold matter due to my lack of exp in that area :)

Comment: i try in console and returns: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3maa5yqjs3druyb/Screenshot%202014-01-30%2015.26.17.png

But in inspect element have nothing inside the div

Comment: Works for me -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4142666/stackoverflow/31jan/inject-script-in-code.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mydiv").html("<script>var dfpValues = DFP.get().values();googletag.display(dfpValues.dfpContainer)</script>");
```

Comment: Please do not provide code-only answer and explain why your solution solves the problem.